# iPhone 5 issue : random behaviour when debug mode is on

Tags: iphone, ios7, iphone-5

When I connect my iPhone 5 with xcode5, then on Iphone Home screen Tap long, after some time, its give worried behaviors. Sometime open any random app installed in my iphone, sometime open browser.

When run app, and press long, any random event occur like some time push new view controller,some time textfield becomeFirstResponder, some time any random keyboard value prees..

Is this OS issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Its not related to xcode. I have noticed the same issue in OS apps as well. For ex. iMessage etc. Random keyboard were pressing.

Looks like OS issue. Quick way to resolve this issue is just restart you device and also upgrade your OS version to more stable version.